# Android - How to detect if an URl scheme redirect was successful?

Tags: android, redirect, url-scheme

I'm working on an Android app that can receive messages via an URl Scheme.

A link gets redirected via PHP to the [URl Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) to pass the message from the browser to the app.

e.g.:

`http://www.example.com/message?text=helloworld`

redirected to:

```
example://message?text=helloworld
```

If a user clicks the link who hasn't the app installed, I would like to display a message in the website.

Is there any way to detect if the user has the app installed or if the redirect was successful?

Comment: are you using a webview?

Comment: AFAIK, not by using a custom scheme. By tying your app to a real HTTP URL, you can arrange to have a Web page be at that real URL to display your message.

Comment: @BasimSherif I'm using the default Android browser and not webview or stagewebview.